# Getting do not have permission error on reading the follower

Tags: ios, getstream-io

I'm trying to read the **follower list** for a particular **feed**. I'm using below `code` for that but getting an **error** as.

> You don't have permission

How to fix that. 
user1 is not the logged in or current user

```
let feed = FlatFeed.init(FeedId.init(feedSlug: "user", userId: "user1"))

feed.followers(completion: { (result) in

    if let followers = try? result.get() {

    } else if let error = result.error {
        print("get error in fetching followers: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

By default we only allow reading followers for your own feeds. If you need to read followers for feeds of other users, please contact support and we will change these permissions for your app.